# How can I apply flex wrap on two different span elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent div, inside which I have a span and a div child. Inside the div child, I have 3 span elements. On the desktop view, the parent div shows up on one line, which is exactly what I want. But in mobile, I want the direct span element and a couple of the children span elements (as many as can fit within the given div width) to show up on the same line, and the rest can wrap underneath.

To visualize my mobile-related issue, I am using a width on the parent div. And even when there is space left after the first span element (which says "Price:"), all the other span elements are going on the second line, which is not what I want.

Here's my code:

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.parent-2 {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="parent-1">
    Price:
  </span>

  <div class="parent-2">
    <span>Sale &emsp;</span>
    <span>Regular &emsp; </span>
    <span>Unit &emsp;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please ensure your snippet is a [example].

Answer (score 0):

If you give `.parent` the `flex-wrap: wrap`-property, it will try to **both** of its child elements as 2 separate, whole containers. That's not want you want, you only want to wrap the `.parent-2`-element, which contains the price units.

You've overcomplicated your problem a bit. Why not just let `flex` do its magic all by itself? Drag the screen size in full page mode, and you can see that all you really need is just `display: flex` to let the wrapping do its work.

Also, don't use `&emsp;` for spacing elements. Use either `margin`, `padding`, `flex-gap` or something along those lines.

```css
/* Demo purpose */
* {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.parent {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

/* Demo purpose */
.parent.full-w {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="parent-1">
    Price:
  </span>

  <div class="parent-2">
    <span>Sale &emsp;</span>
    <span>Regular &emsp; </span>
    <span>Unit &emsp;</span>
    <span>Filler &emsp;</span>
    <span>Filler2 &emsp;</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent full-w">
  <span class="parent-1">
    Price:
  </span>

  <div class="parent-2">
    <span>Sale &emsp;</span>
    <span>Regular &emsp; </span>
    <span>Unit &emsp;</span>
    <span>Filler &emsp;</span>
    <span>Filler2 &emsp;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```